# algorithm for auto-formatting html

Tags: c#, .net

I cant find algorithm for auto-formatting HTML code.

Comment: What is an algorithm for auto-formatting HTML code? Can you please be more specific regarding what you are trying to do? http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: HTML Tidy is definitely the way to go for html formatting with .net

Comment: Please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don´t exactly know what you mean but look at this page [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) with it you can manage a lot of things with html :-)

Comment: The HTML agility pack is a read/write DOM parser, so it could be used to build an HTML formatter, but (unless I'm missing something) won't do that out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an algorithm in the strict sense of the word, then you might do something like:

int counter=0;

Look for html elements:
if you find an opening element, indent it (counter) spaces and increase counter.  otherwise, if you find the closing element decrease counter, and indent the element (counter) spaces.  All other text is indented counter spaces.  Loop...

At the end of the file, counter should be 0 again.
You should never encounter a closing element without having opened that particular type of element, otherwise, you have a badly formatted file.

Answer (score 0):

There's [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) which has a [wrapper for .NET](http://users.rcn.com/creitzel/tidy.html).